# Need Help Figuring Out How to Display New Grid Dimensions Based on User Input number

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am trying to figure out a way where I can create new grid dimensions based on input received from the user. I.e. if the user inputs 10, it will create a 10x10 new grid on the screen.

So far, when the user clicks on the 'clear me!' button, it would prompt the user to input a number from 2 through 100. Once the user enters the number, it empties the container to a blank gray container with no borders. I want it to where if the user inputs a number, it should create new grid columns/rows with a border (which is defined).

I will copy my code down below:

**HTML/Javascript Code:**

````
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="etch.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input id="btn-clear"  type="button" value="Clear 
    Page!">
    <br>
    <div id="container">
 
        
    </div>

    <script>

        let container = 
         document.getElementById('container');
         let clearPage = document.getElementById('btn- 
         clear');

         //function to create 16x16 grid
         function gridSquares() {

            for(let x = 0; x < 256; x++){
                let squares = document.createElement('div');
                squares.className = 'grid-square';
                squares.style.cssText = 'background: #eee';
                squares.style.border = '0.25px solid black';
                container.appendChild(squares);

                //on-click event to get the etch started
                squares.addEventListener('mouseover', 
                function() {
                    squares.style.cssText = 'background: 
                yellow';
                    squares.style.border = '0.25px solid 
                black';
                })

                
            }
                /*
                document.getElementById('btn- 
     clear').addEventListener("click", function() {
                    document.querySelector('div').cssText = 
     'background: #eee';
                })*/

                //btn function
                    document.getElementById('btn- 
         clear').addEventListener('click', () => {
                    
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementById('contai ner').children, item => item.style.cssText = 'background: #eee');
                    // then prompt and do sth
                    let newGrid = window.prompt('Enter grid 
               dimensions ranging from 2 through 100', ' ');
                
                    for (let i = 1; i < newGrid; i++) {
                        let newSquares = 
             document.createElement('div');
                        let newPage = 
             document.querySelectorAll('container');
                        newSquares.className = 'new-grid';                       
                        newPage.display = 'grid';
                        newPage.gridTemplateColumns = 
             'repeat(1, 1fr)' * newGrid;
                        newPage.gridTemplateRows = 
             'repeat(1, 1fr)' * newGrid;
                        newPage.border = '0.25px solid 
               black';
                        
                    }
                })
                    
                
                 
        }
        
        gridSquares();


    </script>
    </body>
    </html>

    **CSS:**

    ```#container {
       height: 98vh;
       display: grid;
       border: 0.25px; solid black;
       /*background: #eee;*/
       grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr); 
       grid-template-rows: repeat(16, 1fr);
       }

       /*.grid-square {
       border: 0.25px solid black;
       background: #eee;

       }*/

       #btn-clear {
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
       border: 3px solid black;
       }```
````